# что делает метод push для js объекта?

Tags: javascript, объекты, push

```
 <!-- Определяем объект "Пользовательская информация" -->
var userData = {
  login: formElements.login.value,
  password: formElements.password.value,
  typeOfTVShow: formElements.typeOfTVShow.value,
  tvShows: [],
  isCinemaddict: formElements.isCinemaddict.value,
  comment: formElements.comment.value
};

 <!-- В переменную var получаем значение, которе лежит в local storage по указанному ключу, в нашем случаем result-->
var results = localStorage.getItem('results') || "[]";

 <!-- JSON - текстовый формат данных, основанный на JavaScript. JSON представляет объекты в виде строки -->
 <!-- Переданная строка results в формате JSON становится JavaScript объектом -->
results = JSON.parse(results);

 <!--??????????????????-->
results.push(userData);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод `push` - **ничего** не делает для объекта, потому по умолчанию у объектов нет такого метода.

Но, в данном случае, `results` - это [**массив**](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array). А, как говорится в справке:
[`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) - добавляет элемент в конец массива.

> что делается в этих строках
>
> ```
> var results = localStorage.getItem('results') || "[]"; 
> results = JSON.parse(results);
> ```

В первой строчке идет попытка получить занчение из [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), либо если его нет присвоить значение по умолчанию `"[]"`

Во второй - получение из строки, полученной на прошлом шаге, *JavaScript объекта*. И тут наступает небольшой диссонанс с предыдущими строками! Так как в них объект рассматривался как экземпляр класса `Object`. В данном же случае речь идет о Javascript значении, которое может быть как экземпляром класса `Object`, так и массивом, примитивом(строкой, числом) и т.д.

В данном случае, судя по значению по умолчанию ожидается именно массив. Хотя на самом деле в строке может оказаться что угодно. в том числе и невалидный JSON, и в этом случае функция [parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) выкинет исключение

Comment: Тогда, что делается в этих строках var results = localStorage.getItem('results') || "[]"; results = JSON.parse(results); ??? не могу понять

Comment: в переменную `result` помещается либо массив данных если они есть, либо пустой массив

Comment: @bsuart2017, обновил ответ. Возможно немного непонятно написано, если так - то стоит уточнить в комментариях что именно еще непонятно

Comment: разобрался, спасибо